# How To POST Request To PHP Endpoint And Process Values

Tags: apex, rest-api, rest, php

I'm trying to send data from Salesforce to an endpoint hosted on an external server. The endpoint is written in PHP that will insert a new record into an external MySQL database.

I've got the connections setup (I.E. I can trigger my apex class that makes the callout and a dummy record is inserted (hard-coded values)).

I'm struggling to actually send dynamic values in my request body and use the values on the other side.

I tried following this guide [Salesforce callout to update external MySQL database](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/132595/salesforce-callout-to-update-external-mysql-database) and have modified it for my use case (below) but I've gotten nowhere.

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint('removed for security');
req.setMethod('POST');

//Create new object to pass through as JSON
Error_Log__c error = new Error_Log__c();
error.process__c = 'Flow';

String JSONString = JSON.serialize(error);            

req.setBody(JSONString);

Http http = new Http();
HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
```

And my PHP code is below

```
$myObjectJSON = $_POST['Error_Log__c'];
$myObject = json_decode($json);
$pp = $myObject->Process__c;
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: @DerekF My question has been modified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `$_POST` superglobal as an array in PHP is more for when you have `x-form-www-urlencoded` data in the request body, not so much when you're sending JSON.

i.e. that's how you would pull data out if you were sending it like `var1=value1&var2=value2` (`$_POST['var1']`)

Since you are working with JSON, you need to get the entirety of the request body and pass it to `json_decode()`. Some brief searching suggests that you should use the `php://input` i/o stream for this.

```php
// The php://input stream can't be used directly
// Gotta use something that can buffer the entirety of the stream 
$postBody = file_get_contents('php://input');

// After which you can decode
// Seems to give you an associative array by default (though you can
//   set a flag or pass an argument to get an object instead)
$data = json_decode($postBody);

// Keep in mind that PHP variables are case-sensitive (unlike Apex, which is definitely
//   the odd duck in the larger family of programming languages)
// Check how your JSONString is being serialized in Apex, you will need to 
//   use the same capitalization in PHP
$process = $data['process__c'];
```

Comment: Hi @DerekF, that makes sense - I appreciate the comment. When I try to echo the $process it returns no value, but if I loop through data and echo each item then I get the value.

Do you know why echoing the value $process alone does not return anything? (This is using the code you helpfully provided)

Comment: @joshholloway like I said, be sure that the capitalization is correct.

Comment: My code below is pretty much what you had, plus the echo, letter for letter in regards to capitals

.`$postBody = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($postBody);

$process = $data->process__c;
echo "\nPROCESS", $process, "\n";`

Comment: @joshholloway I mean that the capitalization is correct _for the data coming from your org_. I had to take a guess at what the capitalization should be. Do a `system.debug()` in your Apex to check. I.e. if it's `PROCESS__c`, then you'd need to do do `$data->PROCESS__c` in php (and not `$data->process__c`. Again, because php variables are _case-sensitive_).

Comment: Hi, you got it correct first time around, it's lowercase coming out of the org, I've even do a manual JSON object with 'gen.writeStartObject()' and I'm still getting the same issue. i cannot reference the field itself but I can loop through the object and get all of the fields & values.

Comment: I've put $data into print_r and capitilisation is correct. `[process__c] => FLOW`

Comment: it has started working, I copied the name from the output itself and that has resolved it, maybe the underscore key on my mac was being read as a different key? Not entirely sure, but you've done it anyway! I really appreciate your time.

Comment: @joshholloway ah, so `json_decode()` gave you an associative array instead of an object. You can either switch to the square bracket notation, or pass in an additional argument to `json_decode()`. At this point, I think this is very much in the realm of PHP, and would point you to their documentation.